# Oracle SQL Get Last String in Parentheses (may include parentheses inside too)

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substring

I'm using this query:

```
SELECT strain.id, TRIM(SUBSTR(strain.name, 1, INSTR(strain.name, '[')-1)) AS name
FROM species_strain strain
```

The query above gives me something like the following:

```
id    name
-----------------------------------------------
100   CfwHE3 (HH3d) Jt1 (CD-1)
101   4GSdg-3t 22sfG/J (mdx (fq) KO)
102   Yf7mMjfel 7(tm1) (SCID)
103   B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11))
104   B29;CD (Atm (line G5))
105   Ifkso30 jel-3
106   13GupSip (te3x) Blhas/J           --------> I don't want to get (te3x)
```

I need a regular expression that would give me the contents of the last set of parentheses (which **MAY OR MAY NOT** include 1 or more set(s) of parentheses inside) - this needs to be at the end of the string. If it's in the middle of the string then I don't want it.

What I want to get is the following:

```
(CD-1)
(mdx (fq) KO)
(SCID)
(tmos (line x11))
(Atm (line G5))
```

So if I copy and paste my entire query I have this but this doesn't take into account the parentheses inside:

```
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_SUBSTR(strain.name, '\(.*?\)', 1, REGEXP_COUNT(strain.name, '\(.*?\)')) AS name
FROM (
  SELECT strain.id, TRIM(SUBSTR(strain.name, 1, INSTR(strain.name, '[')-1)) AS name
  FROM species_strain strain
) strain
WHERE INSTR(strain.name, '(', 1, 1) > 0
```

The query somehow works but if I get another set of parentheses inside the main one it breaks and I lose some data. It returns something like:

```
(CD-1)
(mdx (fq)          ---------> missing KO)
(SCID)
(tmos (line x11)   ---------> missing )
(Atm (line G5)     ---------> missing )
```

#### Additional Requirement

I did forget to mention that the set of parentheses I need should be at the end. If there are other characters after it then I don't want it. I added another row in my example.

Comment: Oracle regex is not that powerful as PCRE or .NET, so, you can only use a predefined level of nesting. Say, if you only have 1 nested parentheses, you may use [`'\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)'`](https://regex101.com/r/tV1xM5/1). Else, you need some parsing features.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew so if I have `Test (get (me) (too))` in Oracle I won't be able to get the `(get (me) (too))`?

Comment: No, like [`Test (get (me) ((me), too))`](https://regex101.com/r/tV1xM5/2). You just cannot match arbitrary recursive subpatterns with the Oracle regex. The pattern I supplied will work with 1 nesting level, it can be enhanced to support 2 levels and it will be more unreadable than it is now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think that's fine. Thanks!

Comment: To actually match the last parentheses in the string, you need to add `[^()]*$` and wrap what is before in a capturing group. Maybe something like [`(\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\))[^()]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/tV1xM5/3).

Comment: For cheaper and quicker maintainability you may be better off writing a PL/SQL function that logically reads the string and returns the set of characters you want.  Even if you work up a regex miracle that handles multiple levels of nested parens, you will be cursed by the person behind you maintaining it and the manager that has to pay for someone to figure it out.  You want that on your conscience?  :-) A function can be called in SQL and achieve the same effect, granted at the cost of some performance.

Comment: @Gary_W I don't do a lot of regex to even be worthy of calling 1/10000000000000000000000th of a miracle. I have never tried creating a function before. Is that the same as creating a view? I ask this because I don't have permission to create views. I provide the query and my senior creates them herself.

Comment: With a bit of effort I was able to find a solution that covers all possible cases (I believe), does not require writing a function, does not use regular expressions at all, doesn't need any parsing features, and doesn't run for hundreds of lines. In general, it is probably best not to opine about something "not being possible" unless one knows for sure; such pronouncements may make others not even try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below uses plain SQL (no procedure/function); it works for any level of nested parentheses and "same-level" parentheses; and it returns `null` whenever the input is `null`, or it doesn't contain any right parentheses, or it contains a right parenthesis but the right-most right parenthesis is unbalanced (there is no left parenthesis, to the left of this right-most right parenthesis, so that the pair is balanced).

At the very bottom I will show the minor adjustment needed to return "the result" only if the right-most right parenthesis is the very last character in the input string, otherwise return null. **This was the OP's edited requirement**.

I created several more input strings for testing. Notice in particular `id = 156`, a case in which a smart parser wouldn't "count" parentheses that are within string literals, or in some other way aren't "normal" parentheses. My solution does NOT go that far - it treats all parentheses the same.

The strategy is to start from the position of the right-most right parenthesis (if there is at least one), and to move left from there, step by step, going only through left parentheses (if there are any) and to test if the parentheses are balanced. That is done easily by comparing the length of the "test string" after all `)` are removed vs. length after all `(` are removed.

Bonus: I was able to write the solution without regular expressions, using only "standard" (non-regexp) string functions. This should help keep it fast.

**Query**:

```
with
     species_str ( id, name) as (
       select 100, 'CfwHE3 (HH3d) Jt1 (CD-1)'         from dual union all
       select 101, '4GSdg-3t 22sfG/J (mdx (fq) KO)'   from dual union all
       select 102, 'Yf7mMjfel 7(tm1) (SCID)'          from dual union all
       select 103, 'B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11))' from dual union all
       select 104, 'B29;CD (Atm (line G5))'           from dual union all
       select 105, 'Ifkso30 jel-3'                    from dual union all
       select 106, '13GupSip (te3x) Blhas/J'          from dual union all
       select 151, ''                                 from dual union all
       select 152, 'try (this (and (this))) ok?'      from dual union all
       select 153, 'try (this (and (this)) ok?)'      from dual union all
       select 154, 'try (this (and) this (ok))?'      from dual union all
       select 155, 'try (this (and (this)'            from dual union all
       select 156, 'right grouping (includging ")")'  from dual union all
       select 157, 'try this out ) ( too'             from dual
     ),
     prep ( id, name, pos ) as (
       select id, name, instr(name, ')', -1)
       from   species_str
     ),
     rec ( id, name, str, len, prev_pos, new_pos, flag ) as (
       select  id, name, substr(name, 1, instr(name, ')', -1)),
               pos, pos - 1, pos, null
         from  prep
       union all
       select  id, name, str, len, new_pos,
               instr(str, '(',  -(len - new_pos + 2)),
               case when length(replace(substr(str, new_pos), '(', '')) =
                         length(replace(substr(str, new_pos), ')', ''))
                    then 1 end
         from  rec
         where prev_pos > 0 and flag is null
     )
select   id, name, case when flag = 1 
              then substr(name, prev_pos, len - prev_pos + 1) end as target
from     rec
where    flag = 1 or prev_pos <= 0 or name is null
order by id;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID NAME                             TARGET                         
---------- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
       100 CfwHE3 (HH3d) Jt1 (CD-1)         (CD-1)                          
       101 4GSdg-3t 22sfG/J (mdx (fq) KO)   (mdx (fq) KO)                   
       102 Yf7mMjfel 7(tm1) (SCID)          (SCID)                          
       103 B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11)) (tmos (line x11))               
       104 B29;CD (Atm (line G5))           (Atm (line G5))                 
       105 Ifkso30 jel-3                                                    
       106 13GupSip (te3x) Blhas/J          (te3x)                          
       151                                                                  
       152 try (this (and (this))) ok?      (this (and (this)))             
       153 try (this (and (this)) ok?)      (this (and (this)) ok?)         
       154 try (this (and) this (ok))?      (this (and) this (ok))          
       155 try (this (and (this)            (this)                          
       156 right grouping (includging ")")                                  
       157 try this out ) ( too                                             

 14 rows selected
```

**Change needed to satisfy the OP's (edited) requirement**:

In the outermost `select` (at the bottom of the code), where we have `case when flag = 1 then...` to define the `target` column, add a condition like so:

```
... , case when flag = 1 and len = length(name) then ...
```

**Output** with this modification:

```
        ID NAME                             TARGET                         
---------- -------------------------------- --------------------------------
       100 CfwHE3 (HH3d) Jt1 (CD-1)         (CD-1)                          
       101 4GSdg-3t 22sfG/J (mdx (fq) KO)   (mdx (fq) KO)                   
       102 Yf7mMjfel 7(tm1) (SCID)          (SCID)                          
       103 B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11)) (tmos (line x11))               
       104 B29;CD (Atm (line G5))           (Atm (line G5))                 
       105 Ifkso30 jel-3                                                    
       106 13GupSip (te3x) Blhas/J                                          
       151                                                                  
       152 try (this (and (this))) ok?                                      
       153 try (this (and (this)) ok?)      (this (and (this)) ok?)         
       154 try (this (and) this (ok))?                                      
       155 try (this (and (this)            (this)                          
       156 right grouping (includging ")")                                  
       157 try this out ) ( too                                             

 14 rows selected
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this. A question though: What is with the right grouping? Why does it not match `includging ")"`? On a side-note, there's really no need to worry about unbalanced parentheses as we created a diagnostics for this. There might be times where it occurs due to data entry errors but we will always correct that as paired parentheses are a must for this string.

Comment: Also you have this: `select id, name, substr(name, 1, instr(name, ')', -1)), pos, pos - 1, pos, null`. Why was there a need to select `pos` twice? Was this intentional?

Comment: Regarding `id=156` - if you read from right to left, you will see that the very last right parenthesis is not balanced - what should be shown in this case? I explained in my post: if the last right-parenthesis is, say, the second in the string, but there is only one left-parenthesis in the whole input, then this is an "unbalanced parentheses" error (exception). I chose to show the "target" as NULL in this case; I could have written the query to return an exception in this case, but that is not usually done in plain SQL. If I were writing a function, this would be a handled exception for sure.

Comment: About `pos` being selected twice: In the recursive query, I carry forward the `len` (the length of the string up to the last right parenthesis), and I also move from right to left to find the first left-parenthesis that gives me a balanced pair. In the very first iteration, `len` and this `pos`(ition) coincide; later, `len` remains constant but the `new_pos` keeps moving to the left. Yes, in the first iteration (the so-called "anchor" branch of the recursive query), the repeated selection of `pos` was intentional and needed; it is used to "initialize" two different "variables".

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again but when I add `STOCK Gt(ROSA26)Sor<sp>tm2(CAG-CHRM3*,-mCitrine)Ute<sp/>/J` to your test cases, the solution failed. It returned `(CAG-CHRM3*,-mCitrine)` when it should return `NULL`.

Comment: OK, I saw your request, please give me a little time to look at it.

Comment: I just tested, and I get NULL for those additional "test" strings. Did you pay attention to the Edit or did you use the query from my initial answer? You must do what I said in the Edit:  add one more condition, `len = length(name)`, to the WHEN condition in the last CASE expression. Re-read the EDIT and make sure you modified my original answer accordingly.

Comment: Ooops, darn. Silly me.. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries, better to ask and to be able to solve the problem! I do the same all the time, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should note that Oracle regex is not that powerful as PCRE or .NET regex. So, you may only use a regex to match specified nested parentheses levels.

The following regex will match the last parentheses in a string with 1 nested parentheses level:

```
\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tV1xM5/4)

This regex won't match strings like `Test (get (me) ((me), too))`. The pattern I supplied will work with 1 nesting level, it can be enhanced to support 2 levels and it will be more unreadable than it is now.

*Details*:

- `\(`  - a `(`
- `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*` - zero or more occurrences of:

  - `\(` a `(`
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
  - `\)` - a closing `)`
  - `[^()]*` - zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a closing `)`
- `$` - the end of string.

Use like

```
regexp_substr(col_name, '\([^()]*(\([^()]*\)[^()]*)*\)$', 1, 1)
```

Comment: This seems to work. Sorry I might not have been very clear with my question's title when I said `last string`. What I meant was that it had to be at the end of the string. There should be no other text after the closing parenthesis. Updating question.

Answer (score 1):

**If creating a function is an option**, then the following function does the job:

```
create or replace
function fn_pars(p_text in varchar2) return varchar2 deterministic as 
  n_count pls_integer := 0;
begin
  if p_text is null or instr(p_text, ')', -1) = 0
    or p_text not like '%)' then
    return null;
  end if;
  for i in reverse 1..length(p_text) loop
    case substr(p_text, i, 1) 
      when ')' then n_count := n_count + 1;
      when '(' then n_count := n_count - 1;
      else null;
    end case;
    if n_count = 0 then 
      return substr(p_text, i);
    end if;
  end loop;
  return p_text;
end fn_pars;
```

Then you can test it:

```
select text,
       fn_pars(text)
  from (
          select 'B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11)) abc' text from dual union all
          select 'B29fj;j(fos) x11 (tmos (line x11))' text from dual union all
          select 'B29fj;j(fos) x11 (t(mo)s (line x11))' text from dual union all
          select '' text from dual union all
          select 'no parentheses' text from dual
       )
```

Result:

```
Text                                    fn_pars(text)
-----------------------------------------------------
B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11)) abc   (null)
B29fj;j(fos) x11 (tmos (line x11))     (tmos (line x11))
B29fj;j(fos) x11 (t(mo)s (line x11))   (t(mo)s (line x11))
(null)                                 (null)
no parentheses                         (null)
```

where *(null)* means no value. :)

The function supports any level of nesting. You can also nest many parentheses at the same level.

Comment: Your last statement really makes me want this solution. So far it throws an error that I don't sufficient privileges. I'll talk to my senior if she could create it for me.

Comment: I was looking at your result and saw that you returned `(tmos (line x11))` even though there were strings after it. I updated the question a couple minutes ago to say that I only need the ones at the end of the column. So if there are characters after the closing parenthesis then I don't want it.

Comment: You mean if the string contains anything else than a parenthesis then the string does not match or should a substring be returned?

Comment: What I mean is that for `Test (me) too` I **DON'T** want to get `(me)`. But if it's `Test me (too)` then I want `(too)`. It's basically the same as my question before but this time I need the text inside the parentheses that is at the end of the string. If it is the middle then I don't want it.

Comment: In your result - the first two shouldn't match because they have `abc` and `asdf` after the closing parenthesis. Hope that clears it.

Comment: Right. Reading with comprehension... I updated the function.

Comment: I'm about to get out of the office. I might be able to test this out first thing in the morning tomorrow. I'll let you know the results. So far the first version worked like you said without the added requirement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one nesting, then the following should work:

```
regexp_substr(col, '[(]([^()]*|[(][^()]*[)])+[)]$', 1, 1)
```

This satisfies all the examples in your question, but it does not allow arbitrary nesting of parentheses.

Comment: So I tried your regex and so far the query is still running: http://pastebin.com/59jy23cb

Comment: My regex is faster as it follows the unroll-the-loop principle. This one contains an alternation and will be executed a bit (or much, depends on the data) slower.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew seems like it. I had the query running for more than 3 minutes before I decided to just end it. Yours was definitely quicker but I did forget 1 important requirement which I included in the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

This works for any depth of nested brackets:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE species_strain ( id, name ) AS
SELECT 100,   'CfwHE3 (HH3d) Jt1 (CD-1)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 101,   '4GSdg-3t 22sfG/J (mdx (fq) KO)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 102,   'Yf7mMjfel 7(tm1) (SCID)' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 103,   'B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11))' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 104,   'B29;CD (Atm (line G5))' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 105,   'Ifkso30 jel-3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 106,   'data (1 (2 (333 (444) 3 (4 (5) 4) 3) 2) 1)' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH tmp ( id, name, pos, depth ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         LENGTH( name ),
         1
  FROM   species_strain
  WHERE  SUBSTR( name, -1 ) = ')'
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         name,
         pos - 1,
         depth + CASE SUBSTR( name, pos - 1, 1 )
                 WHEN '(' THEN -1
                 WHEN ')' THEN +1
                          ELSE 0 END
  FROM   tmp
  WHERE  (  depth > 1
         OR SUBSTR( name, pos -1, 1 ) <> '(' )
  AND    pos > 0
)
SELECT id,
       MAX( name ) AS name,
       MIN( SUBSTR( name, pos - 1 ) ) KEEP ( DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY pos )
         AS bracket
FROM   tmp
GROUP BY id;
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT id,
       name,
       substr( name, start_pos ) AS bracket
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         name,
         LAG( CASE WHEN bracket = '(' AND depth = 1 THEN pos END )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM )
           AS start_pos,
         pos AS end_pos,
         bracket,
         depth
  FROM   (
    SELECT id,
           name,
           COLUMN_VALUE AS pos,
           SUBSTR( name, column_value, 1 ) AS bracket,
           SUM( CASE SUBSTR( name, column_value, 1 ) WHEN '(' THEN 1 ELSE -1 END )
             OVER ( PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS depth
    FROM   species_strain s,
           TABLE(
             CAST(
               MULTISET(
                 SELECT REGEXP_INSTR( s.name, '[()]', 1, LEVEL )
                 FROM   DUAL
                 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( s.name, '[()]' )
               ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
             )
           ) t
    WHERE  SUBSTR( s.name, -1 ) = ')'
  )
)
WHERE bracket = ')'
AND   end_pos = LENGTH( name );
```

**Results**:

```
        ID NAME                                       BRACKET                                  
---------- ------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------
       100 CfwHE3 (HH3d) Jt1 (CD-1)                   (CD-1)                                     
       101 4GSdg-3t 22sfG/J (mdx (fq) KO)             (mdx (fq) KO)                              
       102 Yf7mMjfel 7(tm1) (SCID)                    (SCID)                                     
       103 B29fj;jfos x11 (tmos (line x11))           (tmos (line x11))                          
       104 B29;CD (Atm (line G5))                     (Atm (line G5))                            
       106 data (1 (2 (333 (444) 3 (4 (5) 4) 3) 2) 1) (1 (2 (333 (444) 3 (4 (5) 4) 3) 2) 1)
```

Comment: I think the CONNECT BY is the only option when a function *cannot* be used and you need a pure SQL solution. On the other hand, a cost of the query is 651 in compare with 3 when using a function. For readability/maintainability/performance purpose you'd go for the function.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaszkowiak Updated to use a recursive sub-query factoring clause.

Comment: The OP showed the output with the enclosing parentheses; these solutions do not include them. That can be changed easily if in fact the parentheses are needed. When the input ends with **two** right parentheses, Query 1 deletes **both** of them leaving the output unbalanced. On those inputs, Query 2 works properly. Then: Query 1 goes into an infinite loop and Query 2 produces an unexpected result on the additional test string `'right grouping (includging ")")'` - Q2 returns the inner parenthetical group, disregarding the closing `)`. Working on a general solution...

Comment: @mathguy Fixed, thanks for debugging - the OP does not appear to be considering unbalanced parentheses so, since both queries give the desired answers, I am not going to spend lots of time on that edge case unless requested by the OP.

Comment: Understood. For my own practice, I will work on a general solution (if I find the time) and may post if I can come up with a clean one. Cheers!

Comment: @KrzysztofKaszkowiak - Did you know that the estimated optimizer cost DOES NOT ASSIGN A COST to any function call? You can't use optimizer cost of 3 to speculate that a function-based solution will be more efficient. The solution I posted has an estimated cost of 57 (with about twice as much test data); I believe it would be several times faster than any function-based solution. Whenever you can do something in plain SQL, it is almost certain it will be faster than a PL/SQL solution.

Comment: @KrzysztofKaszkowiak - Regarding CONNECT BY - recursive factored subqueries (recursive CTEs, whatever name you want to use for them) are available since Oracle 11.2.  Absolutely everything that can be done with CONNECT BY can also be done with recursive queries (although the code may sometimes be longer, since Oracle pre-defined certain facilities like SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH and CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF). So, whenever you see a CONNECT_BY solution anywhere, remember there is also a recursive query that can do the same thing (but only available in Oracle 11.2 or higher).